# Why won't this bower package work?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, gridstack

This is my first attempt with using bower packages and NPM. I am trying to use Gridstack.js - [link](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js).

What am I missing? Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the  tags for my html:

```
 <head>
    <link type="text/javascript" href="bower_components/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="grid-stack">
<div class="grid-stack-item"
    data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0"
    data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-stack-item"
    data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0"
    data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
var options = {
    cell_height: 80,
    vertical_margin: 10
};
$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you initialize it with `$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options)`?

Comment: @DanielT. Yeah, I already did.

Comment: We need to see your HTML and JS before we can help.

Comment: @DanielT. Updated.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a script tag for jquery. You have `jquery-ui.min.js`, but not `jquery.min.js`. jQuery UI and Gridstack are both plugins for jQuery, so you will need to load jQuery first before either can work.